# What is the given series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I prove that the following sums:

$\dfrac{1}{4} +\dfrac{1}{4} * \dfrac{1}{3}$

$\dfrac{1}{4} + \dfrac{1}{16} + \dfrac{1}{16}*\dfrac{1}{3}$

$\dfrac{1}{4} + \dfrac{1}{16} + \dfrac{1}{64} + \dfrac{1}{64}*\dfrac{1}{3}$

…..
= $\dfrac{1}{3}$ exactly

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Loks like you add the first n powers of 1/4 together and then add to that 1/3 of the last power you added. It would be routine to get the result in closed form.

Answer (score 3):

All except the last term is a finite geometric sequence.

$a = \dfrac{1}{4}$

$r = \dfrac{1}{4}$

$S_n = a \dfrac{1-r^n}{1-r} =  \dfrac{1}{4} . \dfrac{1-(\dfrac{1}{4})^n}{1-\dfrac{1}{4}}$

$ \dfrac{1}{3} . (1-(\dfrac{1}{4})^n )$

Now adding  $\dfrac{1}{3}$ . (last term)

$ \dfrac{1}{3} . (1-(\dfrac{1}{4})^n ) + \dfrac{1}{3} . (\dfrac{1}{4})^n$

we get $\dfrac{1}{3}$ exactly because the sum of the sequence was $\dfrac{1}{3}$ . (last term) less than $\dfrac{1}{3}$

The series came from a 3-way cake cutting problem. A person who had never seen a 120 degree angle had to cut a cake into 3 equal parts. So the first thing he did was to cut straight down the middle to get 2 parts. Now he is one part short, so he cuts straight across to get 4 quarters.

But there are 3 people to eat the cake so 1 quarter is left over. He could cut the remaining quarter into 3 equal parts and give to each person, so the sum of 1/4 +1/12 is exactly 1/3. But remember, he does not know how to cut into 3 equal parts.

So he again cuts the remaining quarter into 4 equal parts, gives 3 parts to the 3 people and has 1/16 left over. Now he again has the coice to cut the remaining part into 3 parts and end the series or to cut it into 4 parts and have 1 part left to continue the series.

Answer (score 0):

Geometric series, in disguise.

Let $x = (1/4).$

Then

$$x \times (1 + [1/3]) = x \times \frac{1}{3/4} = x \times \frac{1}{1 - [1/4]}$$

$$ x \times \frac{1}{1 - x} = x \times [1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots].$$

Comment: The last term x 1/3 makes it not a geometric series. For an infinite series your formula is OK as its sum tends to 1/3 but this is a finite series where adding the last term x 1/3 makes it exactly equal to 1/3

Comment: @user1648764  I guess it depends on your perspective.  First of all, the first expression, $~\displaystyle \frac{1}{4} + \left[\frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{3}\right]~$ can be reasonably construed to represent the geometric series in disguise.  Then, you can use induction to demonstrate that each re-expression is equal to the previous re-expression.  So, induction indicates (for example) that $$\dfrac{1}{4} + \dfrac{1}{16} + \dfrac{1}{64} + \left[\dfrac{1}{64}\times \dfrac{1}{3}\right]$$ does in fact equal $~\displaystyle \frac{1}{4} + \left[\frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{3}\right].$

Comment: @user1648764 The alternative approach is to reason that each re-expression is simply a disguised form of the original geometric series.  So, you can show that $$\dfrac{1}{4} + \dfrac{1}{16} + \left\{ ~\dfrac{1}{64} + \left[\dfrac{1}{64}\times \dfrac{1}{3}\right] ~\right\}$$ does in fact equal $$\dfrac{1}{4} + \dfrac{1}{16} + \left\{ ~\dfrac{1}{64} + \left[\dfrac{1}{256} + \dfrac{1}{1024} + \cdots\right] ~\right\}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n$ denote the sum:
$$a_n = \frac{1}{4^1}+\frac{1}{4^2}+....+\frac{1}{4^n}+\frac{1}{4^n}\times\frac{1}{3}$$
We need to prove that $a_n = \frac13$ for all $n \ge 1$.

Let $A(n)$ denote the statement $a_n = \frac13$. We give a proof by induction on $a_n$.

**Base Case**:
Clearly, $A(1)$ is true as
$$a_1 = \frac14+\frac14 \times \frac13 = \frac14 + \frac{1}{12} = \frac13$$
**Induction Step**:
We will now show that if $A(k)$ holds, then $A(k+1)$ also holds.
Assume the induction hypothesis that for a particular $k$, $A(k)$ holds. It follows that
$$a_k = \frac13$$
$$\frac{1}{4^1}+\frac{1}{4^2}+....+\frac{1}{4^k}+\frac{1}{4^k}\times\frac{1}{3} = \frac13$$
Multiplying by $\frac14$
$$\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{4^3}+....+\frac{1}{4^{k+1}}+\frac{1}{4^{k+1}}\times\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{12}$$
Adding $\frac14$
$$\frac14+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{4^3}+....+\frac{1}{4^{k+1}}+\frac{1}{4^{k+1}}\times\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{12}+\frac14$$
$$a_{n+1} = \frac13$$ that is, $A(k+1)$ holds, establishing the induction step.

QED.

Comment: although I would have loved it if you'd had shown _your_ work so far.